# IP Address checking got Error

Tags: android

I am with the help of below condtion checking whether the IP is reachable or not

```
if ( InetAddress.getByName(server1IPAddress).isReachable(1000) == false) 
{         
  ...... 
  ......
}
```

Its working correctly with normal IP address 192.168.1.158 
but when i include port number along with the an external IP 61.17.172.4:85 It shows a error **`UnknownHostException`**.

Will any one help me pls

Comment: What happens if you remove port number and just pass ip address? like 61.17.172.4..

Comment: Use InetSocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(ipAddress, portNo);

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, i'm not too familiar with Inetaddress. Try using a comma, for example InetAddress (string ip, string pt). Take a look here : http://nmstl.sourceforge.net/doc/apiuc/classInetAddress.html#a2

Hope this helps

Comment: Actual I am not able to split IP and Port it came from an external source

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's working correctly. Ports designated that way are correct for protocols like http and in URLs but not for host addresses. I think you'll need to strip off the port part to call getByName.

If you have a full url like http://host.com:85/foo/bar.html you can use something like the following to get a host address:

```
public static String extractAddressFromUrl(String url) {
        String urlToProcess = null;

        //find protocol
        int protocolEndIndex = url.indexOf("://");
        if(protocolEndIndex>0) {
            urlToProcess = url.substring(protocolEndIndex + 3);
        } else {
            urlToProcess = url;
        }

        // If we have port number in the address we strip everything
        // after the port number
        int pos = urlToProcess.indexOf(':');
        if (pos >= 0) {
            urlToProcess = urlToProcess.substring(0, pos);
        }

        // If we have resource location in the address then we strip
        // everything after the '/'
        pos = urlToProcess.indexOf('/');
        if (pos >= 0) {
            urlToProcess = urlToProcess.substring(0, pos);
        }

        // If we have ? in the address then we strip
        // everything after the '?'
        pos = urlToProcess.indexOf('?');
        if (pos >= 0) {
            urlToProcess = urlToProcess.substring(0, pos);
        }
        return urlToProcess;
    }
```

Also, if youre trying to find out if a host is available you might consider using [ConnectivityManager.requestRouteToHost()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#requestRouteToHost%28int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the method suggested by mmeyer to split the input string into the IP and port and then use the new InetAddress method? An untested example being ...

```
String urlToProcess = null; /* your input string */

int pos = urlToProcess.indexOf(':'); /* find the : */
if (pos >= 0) {
   ipAddress = urlToProcess.substring(0,pos ); /* return ip without the port */
   portNo = urlToProcess.substring(pos + 1); /* return the port */
}

sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(ipAddress, portNo);

if ( InetAddress.getByName(sockaddr).isReachable(1000) == false) {
...your code....
}
```

Like I said, I'm no expert and I haven't checked the code so take it with a pinch of salt. Its just a combination of everyone's answers.